# How to flush tasks with countdown timers from celery queue

Tags: django, celery

My Celery queue has hundreds of tasks with countdowns that will make them trigger over the next few hours. Is there a way to have these tasks run immediately such that the queue is effectively flushed?

I'm currently planning an upgrade to our server and I want to make sure that there are no background tasks running while the upgrade completes. If I have to wait for these countdowns, that's OK, but I'd rather force the tasks to run instead.

Another option could be to pause processing of the queue until the upgrade is complete, but flushing seems like a better option.

***EDIT***: I've figured out how to find a list of tasks that are scheduled:

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
i = inspect()
tasks = i.scheduled()
```

Now I just need to sort out how to force their execution.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I'm fairly certain I've sorted out roughly how to do this. I'm making this answer a wiki and putting down my notes, in case anybody wants to tune up the general process here.

The general idea is this:

1. Stop adding new items to the queue.
2. Determine any tasks that are queued.
3. Revoke all those tasks using [`result.revoke()`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#revoke-revoking-tasks).
4. Re-start those tasks using some saved state.

Note that this doesn't support adding an `eta` to the items once you re-queue them, as that's probably implementation-specific.

So, to figure out what tasks are queued, you do:

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
i = inspect()
scheduled_tasks = i.scheduled()
```

Which returns a dict, like so:

```
{u'w1.courtlistener.com': [{u'eta': 1414435210.198864,
   u'priority': 6,
   u'request': {u'acknowledged': False,
    u'args': u'(2745724,)',
    u'delivery_info': {u'exchange': u'celery',
     u'priority': None,
     u'routing_key': u'celery'},
    u'hostname': u'w1.courtlistener.com',
    u'id': u'99bc8650-3be1-4d24-81d6-a882d77a8b25',
    u'kwargs': u'{}',
    u'name': u'citations.tasks.update_document_by_id',
    u'time_start': None,
    u'worker_pid': None}}]}
```

The next step is to revoke all those tasks, with something like:

```
from celery.task.control import revoke
with open('revoked_tasks.csv', 'w') as f:
    for worker, tasks in scheduled_tasks.iteritems():
        print "Now processing worker: %s" % worker
        for task in tasks:
            print "Now revoking task: %s. %s with args: %s and kwargs: %s" % \
              (task['request']['id'], task['request']['name'], task['request']['args'], task['request']['kwargs'])
            f.write('%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n' % (worker, task['request']['name'], task['request']['id'], task['request']['args'], task['request']['kwargs']))
            revoke(task['request']['id'], terminate=True)
```

Then, finally, re-run the tasks as you would normally, loading them from your CSV file:

```
with open('revoked_tasks', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        worker, command, id, args, kwargs = line.split("|")
        # Impost task here, something like...
        package, module = command.rsplit('.', 1)
        mod = __import__(package, globals(), locals(), [module])

        # Run the commands, something like...
        mod.__get_attribute__(module).delay(args*, kwargs**)
```